# Getting low fps(13) on yolo tensrflow model

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv, machine-learning, yolo

I am Using this repository for my project https://github.com/LeonLok/Deep-SORT-YOLOv4, It is taking 13 fps but my video has 30 fps. I want to increase my FPS Processing to around 30, Please help me to achieve this FPS Processing.

My System Configurations:

- Nvidia GTX 1060.
- Intel i7 processor.

python script only using GPU memory
[image]

I Have tried this approach :
-> to use GPU decoder i have tried cv2.cudacodec.createVideoReader but no luck [Link](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/17649)

Comment: I boight an Opel Corsa and I can barely drive it with 200 kmh, but I want to use it in racing. How can I increase the kmh?

Comment: @Micka i don't want to put Opel Corsa into race I want to use Opel Corsa with its maximum speed

Comment: reduce your input image size to 32x32

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue might depend on your video card. High fps with good accuracy on weak hardware is something we all want, but it's not a thing. Pick two, or find the balance between three. The best advice I can give you is, look more into your requirements.

Is processing every frame really necessary?

Also this is Stack Overflow. You go here to get help with code issues. Not Hardware issues nor FPS issues. I recommend going to another forum for your issue.

Comment: Thank you for your solution I found that, it is not necessary to process every frame in yolo. I use OpenCV to track and detect the vehicle. if the vehicle pass ROI then yolo runs on that frame.